# Creating a loop function in a step-by-step function list

Tags: c#, loops

Right now, here's what I have:

[image]

What it does is iterate through a list of pre-set functions, the list being configured by the user. It does this by looping through the DataGridList like so:

```
foreach (DataGridRow row in configTable.Items)
{
    ConfigRow crow = (ConfigRow)row.Item; //ConfigRow is just a generic class for the row values
    string val1 = crow.colValue;
    string val2 = crow.colValue2;
    //...Some other, irrelevant code for parsing user-set variables in the values...
    if (actions.actions.ContainsKey(crow.colType))
    {
        ((Action<String, String, String>)actions.actions[crow.colType]).Invoke(crow.colMethod, val1, val2);
    }
}
```

And in my Actions class I have a

```
Dictionary<string, Action<String, String, String>>
```

Named 'actions', which contains the pre-set functions, like this one for gathering source code:

```
actions["Get source"] = (Action<String, String, String>)delegate(String method, String val1, String val2)
{
    using (WebClient wb = new WebClient())
    {
        if (method == "POST")
        {
            wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            variable = wb.UploadString(val1, val2);
        }
        else
        {
            variable = wb.DownloadString(val1);
        }
    }
window.appendConsole("Retrieved contents of '" + val1 + "' using " + method + " method");
};
```

Now, I'd like to add a few pre-set functions for loops, being loop with the method 'start', and loop with the method 'end', possibly a method 'break' if needed. But with the way it works, iterating through each function and executing it, how could I have a loop function? I though of making it so when a loop function is found, it sets a variable as the loop function's index and once it reaches the 'end' function it goes back to the index previously mentioned until set requirements are met, however a problem would arise with multiple loops being used as demonstrated here:

```
loopA
loopB
...
stopB //loopA would stop at stopB and not stopA as it was intented to do.
stopA
```

This problem is an enigma for me and it's killing me because it's a very big feature that's most definitely needed.

Comment: You lost me with the part about looping. Can you elaborate on that you want the program to do with that loop? Couldn't your delegate just contain a loop?

Comment: @usr This is what I'm aiming to get: http://i.imgur.com/Iztj0Qr.png. The red section is the first loop, and the orange section is the second loop nested in the first.

Comment: I guess you'd need to parse the input (which is a flat list) into a tree first. The loops seem to form a tree. Also, each of your methods must also receive an object that allows the method to invoke the methods children (like an `Action invokeChildren`). The method would recursively (and repeatedly) call into other methods, thereby traversing the tree. Does that go in the right direction?

Comment: @usr I was thinking of having `List<int> inside = new List<int>();` and when it meets a loop start and the list doesn't contain its index, it'll add it to the list and once it meets a loop end it will either go back to the last index or if requirements are met it will remove it. So the example I previously posted would have a list containing `3` and `8`. Would this be a good idea?

Comment: My experience is that you don't want to mess around at such a low level. It is probably better if you make your data structures indeed form a tree if the logical model is a tree. All those calculations with indexes are hard to comprehend, to test and to debug.; If you want to go with it I think you could make the loop start indexes a `Stack<int>` and it should work. You could make the stack an input to the method definitions in `actions`.